# Deleting through Datasheet view of SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint, list, event-handling

I have an event handler set up to handle ItemAdded, ItemUpdated and ItemDeleting on a list.

I know 2 of the 3 above are async events and these are causing no end of bother.

When I add 7 items through the datasheet, the event handler copies each item to another list in a subsite.

If I then go to the datasheet view of the Master list and delete multiple rows (or even just 1), I get the Resolve Conflicts screen which says that "Rows you changed were previously changed by X (me). Your changes conflict with that user's changes. For each conflict, discard your changes and keep the other user's changes or retry your changes.

I have to discard all my changes and so the deleted items return again.

Funny thing is, I can delete these 1 by 1 from the Standard List view.

What's causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out I had an update to the ListItem within the event handler and so this was telling it that it had changed again, hence the conflicts.

Doing a SystemUpdate allowed the item to be changed without another event being raised.

Comment: Hi Graeme I also got the same error. How can I get rid off that. Please have a look at [this question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23154/calculated-field-get-modify-date-when-a-particular-column-is-get-changed)!!